# angular 2 how to add element property only if condition is met

Tags: angular

With Angular 2, what is the syntax to add an element property only if a condition is met.
I was thinking of using *ngIf but it just adds or removes the entire element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the property.
The general syntax is `[property]="value or condition"`.

For example:

```
[class.myclass]="condition" [style.height]="value" [selected]="condition"
```

Where condition and value are javascript expressions. Google for "Angular 2 template syntax".